# Why does my powershell upload to lambda treat the directories as files?

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

Using the following script

```
$tmpdir = New-TemporaryFile | %{ rm $_; mkdir $_ }
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
$ziplocation = $tempFile.FullName + ".zip"
$ziplocation 
$filepath = Get-ChildItem $file
$filename = $filepath.Name
$fileWithoutExtension = $filepath.BaseName
$directory = Split-Path -path $file -parent
$sharedFolder = Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath "/shared"
$sharedFolder
$lambdaName = "$($enviroment)__$($fileWithoutExtension)"
$s3path = "$($enviroment)/$($lambdaName).zip"
$s3fullPath = "s3://firmware-repo-source-code/$($enviroment)/$($lambdaName).zip"

Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $tmpdir
"Base file copied"
Rename-Item  -path(Join-Path -Path $tmpdir -ChildPath $filename) -NewName "index.js"

Copy-Item -Path $sharedFolder -Destination $tmpdir -Recurse -Container
"shared files copied"

#Compress-Archive -Path $tmpdir -DestinationPath $ziplocation
Compress-Archive -Path ($tmpdir.FullName + "\*") -DestinationPath $ziplocation
"zip created"

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $lambdaName --zip-file ("fileb://" + $ziplocation)
"Lambda updated"

function New-TemporaryDirectory {
    $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
    [string] $name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)
}
```

I end up with my lambda project structure looking like this:
[image]

I am on a windows machine and running powershell version 5.1.17763.316. I can upload the zip to s3 programmatically and view in the file explorer fine but if I upload that same zip through the console.aws.com I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZIP standard uses / as the path separator, but Compress-Archive in Powershell uses \, so when it is unzipped by Lambda, it thinks they are long file names instead of separated paths.

Comment: Is there a way to use Compress-Archive so it zips files with / in paths? Making a build script and would not want to install 7zip.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use 7zip to properly compress the files in a way AWS accepted it. Not sure what was wrong with the built in powershell method they didn't like.